# Have search return show one employee's information not all. Then be able to edit said employee's information

Tags: python

Create a functionality that makes use of looping and string parsing to search all the employees in the list and return only the information of the employee who has the SSN that matches the one used to search. Then be able to edit the employee's information after having searched them.

```
#Initialize list to store employees' information
lstEmployee = []

#clear the IDLE Shell Window
def cls():
    print("\n"*50)

#display the employee information in the required format
def employeeFormatedInfo (name,ssn,phone,email,salary):
    print("")
    print('                             ---------------  {0:s}  ---------------'.format(name))
    print('SSN: {0:s} '.format(ssn))
    print("")
    print('Phone: {0:s} '.format(phone))
    print("")
    print('Email: {0:s} '.format(email))
    print("")
    print('Salary: ${0:s} '.format(salary))
    print("")
    print("                             ---------------------------------------")
    print("")

#view all employees in the system
def viewEmployeeInfo():
    cls()
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")
    print("               View all employees in the system")
    print("")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")
    if (len(lstEmployee)==0):
        #When no employees in the system, view the "No employee in the list" message
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("               No employees in the list.")
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    else:
        #display all employees in the system
        for i in range(0, len(lstEmployee)):
            line = lstEmployee [i].split(',')
            employeeFormatedInfo(line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])
    try:
        option=int(input('Enter 0 to exit or any key to continue: '))
        if option == 0:
           cls()
    except:
        cls()

#add employee to the system
def addEmployeeToList():
    cls()
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")
    print("                   Add Employee Information")
    print("")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")
    try:
        #allow users to enter the employee Name,SSN,Phone,Email, and Salary
        name=input('Employee Name: ')
        ssn=input('Employee SSN: ')
        phone=input('Employee Phone No.: ')
        email=input('Employee Email: ')
        salary=input('Employee Salary:$ ')
        line = name +',' +ssn +',' +phone +',' +email +',' +salary
        index = len(lstEmployee)
        lstEmployee.insert(index, line)
    except:
        cls()
        addEmployeeToList()
    print("")
    print("Employee information has been successfully add to the list.")
    print("")
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("")
    try:
        #allow users to add new emoloyee or return to the main menu when they enter zero
        option=int(input('Enter 0 to return to main menu, or any other number to add new employee: '))
        if option == 0:
            cls()
        else:
            cls()
            addEmployeeToList()
    except:
        cls()
        addEmployeeToList()   

#Search for employee by SSN
def searchEmployee():
    cls()
    print("--------------- Search for Employee by SSN ---------------\n")
    try:
         if (len(lstEmployee)==0):
            #when no employees in the system, view the "No employee in the list" message
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("               No employees in the list.")
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
        else:
            #display searched employee
            search=int(input("Please enter the SSN of the Employee you wish to search: "))
            cls()
            for search in lstEmployee:
                print('                                        --------------- {0:s} ---------------'.format(*search.split(','), sep="\n"))
                print("")
                print('SSN: {1:s}'.format(*search.split(","), sep="\n"))
                print("")
                print('Phone: {2:s}'.format(*search.split(","), sep="\n"))
                print("")
                print('Email: {3:s}'.format(*search.split(","), sep="\n"))
                print("")
                print('Salary: ${4:s}'.format(*search.split(","), sep="\n"))
                print("")
                print("                                      -----------------------------------------")
                print("")
            try:
                option=int(input('Enter 0 to exit to menu or any key to continue to edit this information: '))
                if option == 0:
                    cls()
            except:
                cls()
    except ValueError:
        print("SSN does not match any employee")
        return searchEmployee()

#display the system "Main Menu"
def printOptions():
    print("--------------- Employee Management System ---------------\n")
    print('There are ( {0:2d} ) employees in the system.'.format(len(lstEmployee)))
    print('\n----------------------------------------------------------')
    print("1. View all employees \n")
    print("2. Add new employee \n")
    print("3. Search for employee by SSN \n") 
    #validate the user selection
    try:
        answer=int(input('Please enter your option number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number")
        return 142
    print("")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")
    return answer

#utilize looping to run the Python script constantly
while True:
    cls()
    mode = printOptions()
    #view all employees in the system
    if mode == 1:
        cls()
        viewEmployeeInfo()
    #add employee to the system
    if mode == 2:
        cls()
        addEmployeeToList()
    #Search and Edit existing employee
    if mode == 3:
        cls()
        searchEmployee()
```

I have gotten as far as having my search returned in the format that is necessary, but it shows all the employees, not just the one employee I need.

Comment: Please include at least 5 rows of dummy data for testing.  It should be text, not a screenshot.  [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

In your `searchEmployee` function, you need to add a condition to check if the employee's SSN matches the one provided by user:

```py
#Search for employee by SSN
def searchEmployee():
    cls()
    print("--------------- Search for Employee by SSN ---------------\n")
    try:
         if (len(lstEmployee)==0):
            #when no employees in the system, view the "No employee in the list" message
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("               No employees in the list.")
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
        else:
            #display searched employee
            search=int(input("Please enter the SSN of the Employee you wish to search: "))
            cls()
            for currentEmployee in lstEmployee:
                if currentEmployee.ssn == search:
                    # TODO: print employee info
                    break
            else
                print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
                print("               Employee with the given SSN not found.")
                print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
            try:
                option=int(input('Enter 0 to exit to menu or any key to continue to edit this information: '))
                if option == 0:
                    cls()
            except:
                cls()
    except ValueError:
        print("SSN does not match any employee")
        return searchEmployee()
```